# Property Transfer from a testcase response to a request in different testcase

Tags: json, rest, testing, automated-tests, soapui

Testing a `rest` service in `SoapUI`, I need to do a property transfer from a testcase response to a request in different test case.

JsonResponse in the first testcase is as follows:

```
     {[{
         "items":[{
         "id": "1234",
         "state": "XYZ",
         "type" : "ABCD"
     },
     {
         "id": "12345",
         "state": "XYZV",
         "type" : "ABCDF"
     }
  ]}
```

The id(just one) from the response has to be directed to the Json request of the second testcase via property transfer

```
    {
         workItemsId: ["1234"],
        field: "ABCD"
    }
```

I have tried using items[0].id, but that transfers only the value. **I need  it as an array in the response.** Any help would be deeply appreciated. I am so new to SOAP-UI.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IMO the easy way to do so is using the property expansion. For you case you can use the follow notation approach `${Test step name#Response#JSONPath}`.

Supposing you have a first testStep named `REST Test Request` with the follow response:

```
{
    "items":[
        {"id": "1234","state": "XYZ","type" : "ABCD"},
        {"id": "12345","state": "XYZV","type" : "ABCDF"}
    ]
}
```

And you want to use the first `id` from `items` array in a second testStep request and setting it inside array you can use the follow notation:

```
{
    workItemsId: [${REST Test Request#Response#$items[0].id}],
    field: "ABCD"
}
```

**UPDATE**

If as you comment you want to use the `JSONPath` expression in a property transfer, add a `Property transfer` testStep, select as source your request, as property `response`, as path language `JSONPath` then put the  expression `$items[0].id` and finally select the property where you want to put the result. Finally your property transfer will looks like:

[image]

Hope it helps,

Comment: Can you suggest me to do the same via a property transfer..pls

Comment: @BinoyCherian Sorry I don't understand your comment, do you mean to get the value of your response using jsonpath in `property transfer`?

Comment: The answer is correct. I would just suggest to use `${Test step name#ResponseAsXml#XPath}` instead. The reason being: if you want to run your tests in a CI environment, the SoapUI Maven plugin was not released for version 5.2, which is where JsonPath support was added. I spent all of yesterday rewriting my JsonPath to XPath for this reason. :(

Comment: @abcif, Yes i would like to get the value of the response using jsonpath in property transfer.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using two test cases for this or just two test steps? 
Anyways, rather than transferring the property directly to next request, you can set it as a property on test case and then use that property in next request with property expansion.
So,

1. create a property "id" on test case.
2. In property transfer step set the value of this property using items[0].id
3. In next request use property expansion to populate the value, so json will look like:

   ```
   {
     workItemsId:["${#TestCase#id}"],
     field: "ABCD"
   }
   ```

Here are more details about property expansion : https://www.soapui.org/scripting---properties/property-expansion.html